# Can IQueryable<> only contain instructions (in the form of expression tree) on how to get the initial sequence, but not

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

1)

```
public class Query<T> : IQueryable<T> ... 
{
              ... 
   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() 
   {
      return((IEnumerable<T>)this.provider.Execute(this.expression)).GetEnumerator();
   }
}

Query<string> someQuery = new Query<string>();
```

`someQuery.Expression` holds the expression tree associated with this particular instance of `IQueryable` and thus describes how to retrieve the initial sequence of items. In the following example `initialSet` variable actually contains a sequence of strings:

```
    string[] initialSet = { };
    var results1 = from x in initialSet
                   where ...
                   select ...;
```

a) Can `someQuery` also contain a sequence of strings, or can it only contain instructions ( in the form of expression tree ) on how to get this initial sequence of strings from some DB?

b) I assume that even if `someQuery` actually contains an initial sequence of strings, it is of no use to `Where` and `Select` operators, since they won't ever operate on this sequence of strings, but instead their job is only to build queries or request queries to be executed ( by calling `IQueryProvider.Execute`)? And for this reason `someQuery` must always contain an expression tree describing how too get the initial sequence of strings, even if `someQuery` already contains this initial sequence?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

c) The way I understood your post is that query provider may contain information about describing the table or at least describing particular DB rows which initial query needs to retrieve. But I didn't interpret your answer as saying that query provider may also contain actual elements required by this initial query ( `someQuery` in our example )?

d) Regardless, I assume even if query provider maintains actual elements, it can only maintain them for initial query? Thus if we apply Linq-to-entity or Linq-to-Sql operators on that initial query, I assume provider will have to query the database. As such, if my assumption are correct then answer to **b)** would be even if query does contain actual elements, when we call `Where` on `someQuery` ( `someQuery.Where` ),query provider will have to retrieve results from a DB, even if this query provider already contains all the elements of  `someQuery`?

e) I only started learning Linq-to-entities, so my question may be too general, but how does EF handle all of this? In other words, when does `ObjectSet<T>` returned by some EF API ( such as `ObjectContext` ), contain actual elements and when does it ( if ever ) contain only logic for retrieving  elements from some data source (such as DB)?

f) Also, even if `ObjectSet<T>`  ( returned by say `ObjectSet` ) does contain actual elements, I assume if we apply Where operator on it ( `ObjectSet<T>.Where` ), query provider will always have to retrieve results from the DB?

Comment: Has my answer to your other recent question answered this for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You wouldn't normally create a `Query<T>` yourself - a query provider would. It can choose to include whatever information it wants. It's most likely to just contain the information about what table it's associated with though.

b) That's entirely up to the query provider. As you saw in the other question, the query provider may end up recognizing when it's reached a `Query<T>` - so it *could* know to ask the `Query<T>` for its strings, if that was appropriate.

c) The query provider wouldn't *usually* contain data itself - but it *could* do. *It's up to the provider.*

d) The query provider may notice that it's within a transaction, and that it's already executed a similar context in the query - it *may* be able to answer the query from within its cache. It's up to the query provider.

e, f) No idea, I've never used Entity Framework in anger.

The answer to almost all of your questions around this is topic is "it's up to the query provider". For details about a *particular* query provider, you should read the documentation for that provider. That should explain when it will make queries etc. It's unclear what you're really trying to get out of these questions - but if you're after a full implementation to study, there are plenty of open source LINQ providers around. You might want to look at NHibernate for example.

Comment: "It's unclear what you're really trying to get out of these questions". Uhm, don't know how to reply to this, but I'm learning something, "what if" pops into my mind and I have to find an answer to it. Is that so bad? I really appreciate your time

Comment: @user702769: I'm glad you're learning - it's not been clear to me that I've been actually helping :)